# How to remove content of file B from file A - duplicates possible

Tags: awk, sed, grep, diff

I need to do some background first cos maybe there's som easier solution but we'll see.

So I have a file in specific format (columns) and order that contains document names. This file has more than 850000 lines. My initial task was to find all documents that needs to be deleted. Usually those documents have some numeric value in last column like for example VC99.
So my task was to delete every document marked with this VC value.
Documents starts with capital letters and have some number in forth column for example 04. To establish where this document ends I had to find line which begins with two or more capital letters and has specific value in for column (equal or lower from previous one).
For example as you can see below document starts with ABC 101... and it's value in forth column is 04 and it's marked as VC99 in last column so I need to remove it from file with all subdocuments.

```
ABC 101 11/11   =       R1A     04      BLABLABLA BLAAAA  ASDDSASDA SADDA           VC22!VC23!VC24!VC25!VC26!VC99!VC27!VC28!VC29!VC30
9476-ABC 555 55/55              B2Z
345 34-BGF 957 22/55            A       3       FREE    ASDADADADADAD.
1551-YTR 101 41/15              A       4/3     FREE    ADADADADADADADADADADADADA              XP1
123 00-DFG 111 11               D       4/3     FREE    ADASDADASDASDADADADAD
1/190 06-YTR 101 11             D       4/3     FREE    ASDADADASD ADADADA ASDADADASDA ADSADADADA
BFD 290 01/28   =       D4B     05      BLABLABLA       
1095-ANT 290 01/28              G2Z
131 61-ANT 290 01/28            A       3       FREE    SASDADADADADAD.
1551-ANT 290 01/27              A       4/3     FREE    SASDADADAASDADADADADASDADADADADAD       XP1
1/155 18-ANT 290 01/10          A       4/3     FREE    ASDADADADADAD             XP1
21/155 18-ANT 290 01/21         A       4/1     FREE    ASDADADADADADASDADADADADAD
DFT 290 9985    =       T4      03      BLOCK   APCLOB  XIG/DO
1095-DFG 290 9985               R2
1551-DFG 290 9985               B       1/7     FREE    ASDADADADADAD
1/1551-DFG 290 9985             B       1/7     FREE    FASDADADADADADARASDADADADADAD AASDADADADADADOB
2/155 18-DFG 290 9985           A       1/L     FREE    AASDADADADADAD PASDADADADADAD CASDADADADADAD ASDADADADADAD
1/190 83-DFG 290 9985           A       1/L     FREE    APASDADADADADADON PASDADADADADADL ASDADADADADAD ASDADADADADAD
131 61-DFG 290 9985             B       3       FREE    SASDADADADADADPEC.
DZZB 987 2242   =       F5Y     04      SOFTWARE UNIT   APCLOBU XIG/DO
1095-DFGY 987 2242              R2A
190 55-DFGY 987 2242            J       1/2/7   FREE    SASDADADADADADO.
155 14-DFGY 987 2242            D       2/7     FREE    APASDADADADADADURV
2/109 26-DFGY 987 2242          B       3/7     FREE    CHAASDADADADADADTION
5/109 26-DFGY 987 2242          D       3/7     FREE    CHASDADADADADADRMAASDADADADADADON
190 73-DFGY 987 2242            B       3/7     FREE    AASDADADADADADRAM
152 01-DFGY 987 2242            -----   B
ZXC 290 0004    =       T5      03      FUNCTION BLOCK  CAPPGEN XIG/D           VC22!VC23!VC24!VC25!VC26!VC99!VC27!VC28!VC29!VC30
1095-DFG 290 0004               R2
2/155 18-DFG 290 0004           B       1/L     FREE    CAPASDADADADADADN
131 61-DFG 290 0004             B       3       FREE    STRUASDADADADADADC.
1551-DFG 216 2530               B       4/1/7   FREE    BLOASDADADADADADNTING
1/1551-DFG 216 2530             B       4/1/7   FREE    BLOCASDADADADADADHART
1/190 83-DFG 216 1642           J       4/1/L   FREE    CALASDADADADADADTHASDADADADADADCASDADADADADADG
DFFT 987 9426   =       D5W     02      SOFTWARE UNIT   CAASDADADADADADNU        XIG/DO
1095-DFGY 987 9426              DF2
190 55-DFGY 987 9426            E       1/2/7   FREE    CAASDADADADADADAM
155 14-DFGY 987 9426            C       2/7     FREE    CAPPASDADADADADADRV
3/109 26-DFGY 987 9426          C       3/7     FREE    CHAASDADADADADADTION
4/109 26-DFGY 987 9426          C       3/7     FREE    CASDADADADADADON
5/109 26-DFGY 987 9426          B       3/7     FREE    CHASDADADADADADTION
190 73-DFGY 987 9426            D       3/7     FREE    CAASDADADADADADAM
152 01-DFGY 987 9426            ZX4     B
1/1521-DFGY 987 9426            C       3/7     FREE    BLASDADADADADADASDADADADADADASDADADADADADINT
2/152 83-DFGY 987 9426          B       3/7     FREE    BAASDADADADADADDADADADADASDADADADADADPORASDADADADADADPGEN
```

In this example every line starting from ABC 101 11/11 till DFT 290 9985 should be deleted. 
And then again everything starting from ZXC 290 0004 till DFFT 987 9426 should be deleted.
Basically we can say that I want to delete anything between two patterns and that's how I started.

My general idea was to extract all document names marked with VC99 with value from forth column and I've done this using this command

```
grep "^[A-Z][A-Z].*=.*0[0-7].*V.[9-9][9-9].*" base.txt | awk -F "\t" {'printf ("%5s\t%s\n", $1, $4)'} > delete
```

At this point I had file called delete with two values document name and value assigned to it and it looks like that

```
ABC 101 11/11   04
ZXC 290 0004    03
```

Unfortunately a lot of names contains slashes so I couldn't pass them easy to my next awk command and this was a first bump on a road but I've found solution for that.
I've used sed to escape slashes few times so that next awk command could work.

```
sed 's#/#\\\\/#g' delete > delete_fixed
```

Now my fixed file looked like this

```
ABC 101 11\\/11 04
ZXC 290 0004    03
```

Now I was able to pass those variables into awk and search for pattern using this little script which I partially found on this portal.

```
while IFS=$'\t' read var1 var2
do
awk -F "\t" '/^'"$var1"'/{flag=1;print;next}/^[A-Z][A-Z]/ && ($4 <= '"$var2"'){flag=0}flag' base.txt >> output
done < delete_fixed
```

After few test I was sure that I have a full list of lines that I need to remove from my base.txt which for this example looks like this

```
ABC 101 11/11   =       R1A     04      BLABLABLA BLAAAA  ASDDSASDA SADDA           VC22!VC23!VC24!VC25!VC26!VC99!VC27!VC28!VC29!VC30
9476-ABC 555 55/55              B2Z
345 34-BGF 957 22/55            A       3       FREE    ASDADADADADAD.
1551-YTR 101 41/15              A       4/3     FREE    ADADADADADADADADADADADADA              XP1
123 00-DFG 111 11               D       4/3     FREE    ADASDADASDASDADADADAD
1/190 06-YTR 101 11             D       4/3     FREE    ASDADADASD ADADADA ASDADADASDA ADSADADADA
BFD 290 01/28   =       D4B     05      BLABLABLA       
1095-ANT 290 01/28              G2Z
131 61-ANT 290 01/28            A       3       FREE    SASDADADADADAD.
1551-ANT 290 01/27              A       4/3     FREE    SASDADADAASDADADADADASDADADADADAD       XP1
1/155 18-ANT 290 01/10          A       4/3     FREE    ASDADADADADAD             XP1
21/155 18-ANT 290 01/21         A       4/1     FREE    ASDADADADADADASDADADADADAD
ZXC 290 0004    =       T5      03      FUNCTION BLOCK  CAPPGEN XIG/D           VC22!VC23!VC24!VC25!VC26!VC99!VC27!VC28!VC29!VC30
1095-DFG 290 0004               R2
2/155 18-DFG 290 0004           B       1/L     FREE    CAPASDADADADADADN
131 61-DFG 290 0004             B       3       FREE    STRUASDADADADADADC.
1551-DFG 216 2530               B       4/1/7   FREE    BLOASDADADADADADNTING
1/1551-DFG 216 2530             B       4/1/7   FREE    BLOCASDADADADADADHART
1/190 83-DFG 216 1642           J       4/1/L   FREE    CALASDADADADADADTHASDADADADADADCASDADADADADADG
```

And as you can assume judging by the tile I'm stuck.
I don't know how to remove those exact lines from my base.txt file.
I've tried grep

```
grep -F -x -v -f output base.txt > final
```

but it's too greedy and removes too much possibly cos of duplicates.

The worst part is that I cannot sort this file nor change its structure cos this file will be imported to other tool so I con only remove lines.

I've also tried diff to see only differences but diss adds some characters and changes structure (or I don't know how to use it properly).

My idea is to somehow start deleting from line which is first exact match and then proceed downwards and don't go back to the begining of the file or something like this. Or maybe there's a way to do it along with my awk pattern search?

I'll be grateful for any advice at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort out the logic in `awk` much easier than doing it with multiple tools. the following `awk` code will check the document/sub-document header lines and then setup a flag(`skip`) to identify if a line should be skipped or printed.

```
$ cat t.15.awk
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t"; }

# document/subdocument header started with at least two Uppercase letters 
# and only contain numbers in the 4th field.
function is_document_header() {
    return /^[A-Z][A-Z]/ && $4 ~ /^[0-9]+$/
}

# the target document header must have VC99 as a standalone word in the last column
function has_vc99() {
    return $NF ~ /\<VC99\>/
}

# find the line matching document/subdocument header, flag it accordingly
is_document_header() {
    # set up the skip flag
    skip = has_vc99() ? 1 : $4 <= prev_f4 ? 0 : skip;

    # save $4 in the previous docuement header to prev_f4, remove
    # the if(..) condition if sub-documents also counted
    if (has_vc99()) prev_f4 = $4;
}

# print only when skip is 0
!skip { print }
```

then run the awk command:

```
$ awk -f t.15.awk file.txt
```

BTW. in your sample text, the first document which starts with `ABC 101` does not contain `VC99`.

Comment: jxc you're a god of awk to me starting from now ;)

I've tested it on my 60MB file and it looks fine. I need to check it thoroughly cos it's very very large but after quick check I didn't found any errors so from my point of view it's solved.

One more quick question if I need to remove for example VC33 i just need to change this value return $NF ~ /\<VC99\>/ right? Rest of it is just a function name.

PS. I had to modify this file before posting (somehow sensitive data) and I've done a typo with this VC99 so sorry for that.

Comment: @Arukado glad it helped:). For the pattern, yes, you just need to modify it from VC33 to VC99. `\<` and `\>` are just word boundary, so that VC990 won't match. to add more than one patterns, you can do something like `$NF ~ /\<(VC99|VC33)\>/`